# Uncountability of admissible topological stratifications

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

I'm not sure if this is trivial. Can someone please provide an example of a space which admits uncountably many topological stratifications? How about up to homeomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

You can take the real line as $(-\infty,x) \cup (x,\infty)$ stratified higher than $\{x\}$, for every real number $x$. But these certainly are all homeomorphic.

Judging by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276228) and the Whitney embedding theorem, there are uncountably many different 2-dimensional strata of $\mathbf R^4$ (as there are uncountably many non-compact surfaces).

With the weaker notion of "poset stratification" as in [Lurie Appendix A.5](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HA.pdf#page=1421), you can also do some finagling with the power set of a countably infinite poset (the strata can still be topological spaces, but their dimensions may not correspond to their stratum order).

Comment: Do you think the same can be said for a compact space?

Comment: @gian I am not sure, but I would guess yes, maybe by using the stereographic projection of $\mathbf R^4$ onto $S^4$. Then you probably wouldn't have surfaces as strata, but more general topological spaces.